# custom attributes selecting and assigning values

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul class="slist single required" id="list-fieldtype" data-vt-name="list-fieldtype" >
            <li style="float:none;"><a class="sbox selected" data-vt-value="type_text" data-vt-selected="1">Text</a></li>
            <li style="float:none;"><a class="sbox" data-vt-value="type_number" data-vt-selected="0" >Number</a></li>
            <li style="float:none;"><a class="sbox" data-vt-value="type_date" data-vt-selected="0" >Date</a></li>
            <li style="float:none;"><a class="sbox" data-vt-value="type_yesno" data-vt-selected="0" >Yes/No</a></li>
            <li style="float:none;"><a class="sbox" data-vt-value="type_multi" data-vt-selected="0" >Multiple Choice Answers</a></li>
        </ul>

var $selected = $('.selected');
var new_fieldtype= $("#list-fieldtype").find( $selected ).removeClass('selected'); //this works


var new_fieldtype= $("#list-fieldtype>li>a").find( $selected ).data('vt-selected','0'); // does not work
         $("#list-fieldtype").find( 'type_text' ).addClass('selected'); // does not work
         $("#list-fieldtype>a[data-vt-value=type_text]").addClass('selected'); // does not work
```

How do i make the last three statements work ?? any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? **A waste of time!**

Comment: i have a cancel button when i click that the values should return to original so for eg if i selected type_multi and i pressed cancel button type_multi the selected on type-multi should be removed (which is happening ) but if i want to add the "selected" class to type_text  it is not happening

Comment: It's still not clear enough, :(

Comment: Still doesn't answer the original question..

Comment: @gdoron please don't be presumptuous i had looked up quite a few forums and even stack overflow i tired it for a 1 hour so that's why i posted it online....if the question wasnt well formed my apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) can only be used to **get** the value of data attributes, **not set them**. You have to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the value of attributes.

```
 $selected.attr('data-vt-selected', 0);
```

If your data attibute key if `data-vt-value`, the key to pass to [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is `vtValue`

```
 var value = $selected.data('vtSelected');
```

For the last statement, the selector is wrong: the anchor is not a direct child of the UL !

```
$('#list-fieldtype > a[data-vt-value=type_text]')
// should be
$('#list-fieldtype a[data-vt-value=type_text]')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/y5GJ7/)**

*Note it is pointless to do `$("#list-fieldtype").find( $selected )`. `$selected` is already the element you want to work with, so use it directly.*

Comment: thanks it works...cant believe i got stumped on this one....